# Comparator: Comparing 2 objects with field which can be null

Tags: java, lambda, comparator, comparable

I need to write a `Comparator` by implementing a typical compare-method of a default comparator. This is given due to the interface I need to implement.

My objects are products with an `Integer` field `vintage` which can be `null`. Code is as following:

```
@Override
public int compare ( IProduct product1, IProduct product2 ) throws ProductComparisonException
{

    if ( product1 == null && product2 == null )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ( product1 == null && product2 != null )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( product1 != null && product2 == null )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    IProductData productData1 = (IProductData ) product1.getProvidedProductData();
    IProductData productData2 = (IProductData ) product2.getProvidedProductData();

    if ( productData1.getVintage() == null && productData2.getVintage() == null )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ( productData1.getVintage() == null && productData2.getVintage() != null )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( productData1.getVintage() != null && productData2.getVintage() == null )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return productData2.getVintage().compareTo( productData2.getVintage() );
}
```

I am not satisfied with this, as I have a lot of duplicate code and I'm sure there's a better way to do this... Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Requests for improvements for already working code are a better fit for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you're using Java 8, you may want to use the `Comparator.nullsFirst` method to avoid that null-related boilerplate.

Comment: Do you persist this objects into database? Or does it contain **unique id**?

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, I saw this too - but I kinda not getting what argument is needed for the nullsFirst-Method...

Comment: @oleg.cherednik yes, each product holds a unique id

Comment: **BY THE WAY** According to `Object.equals`, `null != null`

Comment: @oleg.cherednik you can't call `Object.equals` on a null object as that would throw a NullPointerException. If you mean `Objects.equals`, then two nulls compare equal; i.e. `Objects.equals(null, null)` returns `true`. In SQL, on the other hand,  `NULL = NULL` is not true, but then neither is `NULL <> NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one?:

```
Comparator<IProduct> comparator = (p1, p2) -> {
    Integer v1 = p1 != null ? p1.getProvidedProductData() : null;
    Integer v2 = p2 != null ? p2.getProvidedProductData() : null;

    if (v1 == null ^ v2 == null)
        return v1 != null ? 1 : -1;

    return v1 != null ? v1.compareTo(v2) : 0;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your `Comparator`s in `Comparator.nullsFirst` to avoid dealing with possibly `null`able parameters.

You need two `Comparator`s merged with `Comparator#thenComparing`:

1. `nullsFirst(naturalOrder())` to compare `IProduct`s first;
2. `nullsFirst(comparing(p -> p...getVintage())` to compare their `Vintage`s secondly.

   ```
   Comparator<IProduct> comparator =
       nullsFirst(Comparator.<IProduct>naturalOrder())
           .thenComparing(nullsFirst(
               comparing(p -> p.getProvidedProductData().getVintage())
           )
       );
   ```

This approach compares `IProduct` naturally which you apparently don't want to do. (You didn't compare them at all).

Then you might write `IProduct p1, IProduct p2) -> 0` to continue comparing `Vintage`s after neither of two `IProduct`s is `null`.

```
 Comparator<IProduct> comparator =
        nullsFirst((IProduct p1, IProduct p2) -> 0)
            .thenComparing(nullsFirst(
                 comparing(p -> p.getProvidedProductData().getVintage())
            )
        );
```

If `getVintage` returns an `int`, you could use `Comparator.comparingInt` instead of `Comparator.comparing`:

```
comparingInt(p -> p.getProvidedProductData().getVintage())
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use (I assume you are on Java8+ since you tagged the question with **`lambda`**)
either of the following methods from [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
public static <T> Comparator<T> nullsFirst(Comparator<? super T> comparator)
public static <T> Comparator<T> nullsLast(Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) methods introduced in Java 8 and use a method reference e.g.:

```
Comparator.comparing(IProductData::getVintage, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
```

Comment: How do you use this with an argument in the getter? For instance an idx and you have to call IProductData.getVintage(idx)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to generalise the null checks.

```
public int compare(IProduct product1, IProduct product2) throws ProductComparisonException {
    Integer diff = nullCompare(product1, product2);
    if(diff != null) return diff;

    IProductData productData1 = (IProductData)product1.getProvidedProductData();
    IProductData productData2 = (IProductData)product2.getProvidedProductData();

    diff = nullCompare(productData1.getVintage(), productData2.getVintage());
    if(diff != null) return diff;

    return productData2.getVintage().compareTo(productData2.getVintage());
}

// Using Integer so I can return `null`.
private Integer nullCompare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (o1 == null && o2 != null) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (o1 != null && o2 == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    return null;
}
```